# Почему не работает код? (Python)

Tags: python

Мой код:

```
text = open('Города.txt', 'r', encoding='cp1251')
print(text.read())
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User_2019\Downloads\Игра в города.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(text.read())
  File "C:\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 1833: character maps to <undefined>
```

Что это значит, и как это исправить?

Comment: Потому что к кодировке cp1251 не существует символа с кодом 0x98, а значит ваш файл Города.txt на самом деле не в кодировке cp1251, а в какой-то другой

Comment: Спасибо! Оказалось, utf-8.